# C++ Condition to break apart time in string

Tags: c++, time

I have an issue with my code, involving how a string data member which represents time is taken, processed by the number of colons it holds, then separated and converted to integers.

The goal:
 Take a string of time, represented in the form ##:##:##:## separated by 1 to 3 colons, e.g., 1:13:0:59, and "Chop up" the individual pieces between colons.

Leading day and hours fields that are zero may be omitted, so 0:0:0:12, 0:0:12, and 0:12 are all acceptable input forms for "12 seconds". "12" is not acceptable. However, values may exceed the conventional limits on seconds, minutes, and hours. For example, 25:3:90 and 1:1:4:30 .

When I give an input of say, 0:01, minutes gets the entire value. I'm not sure of another way to break apart an string and create separate integers from it.

Here is my code so far.

```
struct Times {
    int days;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    string time;

    void string_to_ints(string& s);
}

void string_to_ints(string& s) {
 // count the amount of colons
 for (int i = 0; i < time.length(); i++) {
     if (time[i] == ':')
     count++;
  }

 // initialize days hours minutes and seconds
if (count == 3) {

    day = time.substr(0, ':');
     d = day.size();
      hour = time.substr( d+1, ':');
       h = hour.size();
        min = time.substr( h+1, ':');
         m = min.size();
          sec = time.substr( m);
           ss= time.size();
 }
// initialize hours, minutes and seconds
if (count == 2) {
   hour = time.substr( 0, ':');
    h = hour.size();
     min = time.substr( h+1, ':');
      m = min.size();
       sec = time.substr( m);
        ss = time.size();
}

// initialize minutes and seconds
if (count == 1) {
   min = time.substr(0, ':');
     m = min.size();
      sec = time.substr( m );
       ss = time.size();
}

// convert the strings to integers
stringstream buffer(sec);
buffer >> seconds;

stringstream buffer2(min);
  buffer2>> minutes;

stringstream buffer3(hour);
  buffer3 >> hours;

stringstream buffer4(day);
  buffer4 >> days;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Instead of using `.size()`, you can use `std::stoi(...)`

Comment: I see. The main thing that I can't seem to get is for it to handle a string by the "characters" between colons.

Comment: `substr` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. The second parameter is the length of the substring, not the character that should terminate it. `':'` happens to have ASCII code of 58, so you keep asking for a substring that's 58 characters long. You are looking for `string::find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string time_str = "1:13:0:59";
    istringstream iss(time_str);
    string temp;
    int days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;

    size_t ndelims = count(time_str.begin(), time_str.end(), ':');
    int count = 0;


    if (ndelims == 3) {
        while(getline(iss, temp, ':')) {
            cout << atoi(temp.c_str()) << endl;

            if (count == 0) {
                days = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if(count == 1) {
                hours = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if(count == 2) {
                minutes = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if (count == 3) {
                seconds = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            count = count + 1;          
        }
        cout << days << " " << hours << " " << minutes << " " << seconds << endl;
    }
    else if (ndelims == 2) {
        while(getline(iss, temp, ':')) {
            cout << atoi(temp.c_str()) << endl;
            if(count == 0) {
                hours = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if(count == 1) {
                minutes = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if (count == 2) {
                seconds = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            count = count + 1;          
        }
        cout << days << " " << hours << " " << minutes << " " << seconds << endl;
    }
    else if(ndelims == 1) {
        while(getline(iss, temp, ':')) {
            cout << atoi(temp.c_str()) << endl;
            if(count == 0) {
                minutes = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            else if (count == 1) {
                seconds = atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            count = count + 1;          
        }
        cout << days << " " << hours << " " << minutes << " " << seconds << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works by counting the number of delimiters `(':')` in the string, and breaking it up into its constituent tokens (which will be the number of delimiters found + 1).

Then, realizing that the rightmost token is always seconds, and the next right-most is for minutes, etc., we can write the code as the above, **which gives the solution you desire**.

Comment: That works... PERFECTLY!!!! What a great way to do that. I've only been coding for around 2 years now.

Comment: @Davey: I'm glad my solution was of use to you. If so, please consider it for acceptance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok to break apart the string using delimiter as ":".
This works on char arrays. So you will have to use a bit of coaxing.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/